# Why notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work in my adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android application i have 2 fragment(MainFragment and FavoriteFragment)
In FavoriteFragment when i click button(delete from favoritelist) notifyItemRemoved method doesn't work form me

**ItemAdapter**

```
holder.btn_maqal.setOnClickListener {
            if (!db!!.searchInFavoriteTable(item)) {
                holder.btn_maqal.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black_full)
                db!!.saveFavorite(item)
                Snackbar.make(holder.itemView, "Added to favorite list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                notifyDataSetChanged()


            } else {
                holder.btn_maqal.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black)
                db!!.deleteFromFavorite(item)
                Snackbar.make(holder.itemView, "Deleted from favorite list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                update(position)
            }
        }
```

**Update method**

```
fun update(position: Int) {
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it not remove the item in the recycler view? Maybe post your whole adapter class or at least the onBindViewHolder function.

Comment: Provide complete adapter class. Have you updated your data source (List) before calling update?